# How do I instantiate a nested private static class java

Tags: java

Lets say I have some nested classes

```
class A{
  private static class B{}
  static class C{ 
    B b;
    C(B b){
        this.b=b;
    }
    int foo(){
        return 42;
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to instantiate the private static class B by doing the following

```
new A.C(new A.B())
```

but because B is private I'm unable to do this.
What is a way of constructing class C with a class B?

Comment: In which class are you trying to construct the instance of class C?

Comment: Provide a full code which is a [MCVE]

Comment: You are trying to pass a private member `class B` into a public constructor of  `class C`. That defeats the purpose of making  `class B` private. Only place where this code will work is in `class A` itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either make `B` non private, or provide a helper method in `A` to create `C`:

```
class A{
  private static class B{}
  static class C{ 
    B b;
    C(B b){
        this.b=b;
    }
    int foo(){
        return 42;
    }
  }
  static createC() {
    return new C(new B());
  }
}
```

So that outside of `A`, you can create an instance of `C` like this:

```
A.C myc = A.create();
```

Note that since `B` is not visible outside, the constructor of `C` is useless, so you can make that private.

Answer (score -2):

If you're just trying to do a test and get around an assertion error, then you can instantiate c with a null value for b, then make an anonymous class and overwrite foo.

`new A.C(null){int foo(){return 42;}}`